# Both et alike : Interpretation en français

Tags: traduction, anglais

En anglais on peut dire :

> The importance of protecting rainforests from human invasion is
>   increasingly realized by developing and developed countries alike.

ou de manière équivalente :

> The importance of protecting rainforests from human invasion is
>   increasingly realized by both developing and developed countries.

En français, toutes les deux variantes, sont-elles rendues par une seule phrase ?

> L'importance de la protection des forêts tropicales contre l'invasion
>   humaine est de plus en plus réalisée à la fois par les pays en
>   développement et les pays développés.

Autrement dit, *both* et *alike* sont-ils rendus en français de la même façon dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il y a une nuance entre *both* et *alike* : *alike* implique que les deux possibilités sont réalisées de la même manière et à peu près dans la même quantité, alors que *both* n'implique pas cela. On retrouve cette nuance en français à divers degrés.

> *The importance of protecting rainforests from human invasion is increasingly realized by **both** developing and developed countries.*
>   L'importance de protéger les forêts tropicales des invasions humaines fait de plus en plus l'objet d'une prise de conscience **à la fois** dans les pays développés et dans les pays en [voie de] développement.

(*Réaliser* est un faux amis.)

« À la fois » est neutre : il se peut que la prise de conscience soit de nature différente ou à un degré différents suivant les pays. D'autres possibilités :

- « dans les pays développés **comme** dans les pays en développement » : à peu près synonyme.
- « dans les pays développés **tout comme** dans les pays en développement » : à peu près synonyme, mais insiste plus sur le fait qu'on retrouve le même effet dans les pays en développement.
- « dans les pays développés **aussi bien que** dans les pays en développement » : pas forcément exactement au même degré et de la même manière, mais quand même avec une certaine similitude.
- « dans les pays développés **de même que** dans les pays en développement » : pas forcément exactement au même degré et de la même manière, mais quand même avec une certaine similitude.
- « dans les pays développés **de la même manière que** dans les pays en développement » : de la même manière mais pas forcément au même degré.
- « dans les pays développés **tout autant que** dans les pays en développement » : autant mais pas forcément de la même manière.
- « dans les pays développés **exactement comme** dans les pays en développement » : à la fois de la même manière et au même degré.

Answer (score 4):

Dans ce contexte, ça ne change effectivement rien. Une traduction plus littérale de "alike" pourrait être :

- "et/mais également/aussi" ("et"=neutre, "mais"=emphase)
- "ainsi que"

... et certainement beaucoup d'autres tournures.

Answer (score 3):

*Both* et *alike* ont effectivement des sens proches, encore que *alike* n'est pas limité à deux parties.

Un problème avec la phrase suggérée est que *l'importance **est réalisée*** n'est pas vraiment utilisable en français. Ça signifierait quelque chose comme *The importance is performed...*

Voilà comment tu pourrais écrire ça :

> Les pays en développement et les pays développés ont, **les uns comme les autres**, de plus en plus pris conscience de l'importance de la protection des forêts tropicales contre l'invasion humaine.